# Polynomial that gives specific remainder

Tags: polynomials

How can I find a quintic polynomial which gives the remainder of 2x+3 when it's divided by x^2-4x+5? Can somebody explain me the process?

Comment: Just compute $x^3(x^2-4x+5)+(2x+3)$.

Comment: Hint: when you divide a quintic by a quadratic what you get as a quotient?

Comment: How would you find a number $\gt 50$ that gives remainder $5$ when it's divided by $7$?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of polynomial division $P(x)=(x^2-4x+5)(ax^3+bx+c)+2x+3$

and we need $a\ne 0$ so that the term in $x^5$ is not null, but except for this condition you can set any values for $a,b,c$.